# How to create a "interaction box" after receive a share intent?

Tags: android

[image: google keep interaction box]

On that image what I did was share a Netflix show with the app Google Keep.
After you share something with Google Keep they show this box that works above the other app (Netflix on that specific case), and with that, you can create a note and save it.

I want to know how that works, how they did that little screen, I already know how to put my app as an option to receive a share intent and manipulate the URL, but I want to know how to create this little box that the user can interact after he shares something with my app.
What should I look for?

[image: the app "Pocket" also does something similar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show dialog over other application you need to make sure below things:

Your dialog activity must be part of a separate task from the base activity, so that it when it is shown above the other application, it does not pull the base activity above the other application as well (see `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`)

Your dialog activity must be brought to the front, so that it is still shown if the activity it is being launched from is running in the background (see `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`).

Your dialog activity must have a translucent theme, to allow the other application to show up behind it (see `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`).

Your dialog activity must not fill the screen, for the same reason (see `Window.setLayout`).

Your dialog activity must show a dialog somehow, e.g. by creating a class which extends the `Dialog` class directly.